# Recycler View does not show data fetched from Firestore database

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching some data from a `Firestore` database and showing it in a `RecyclerView`. The data is being fetched into the app as I can see it with a `Log.d()` statement. However, the data does not appear in the `RecyclerView`.

My `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore db;
List<MenuItem> foodList;
RecyclerView menulist;
MenuAdapter madap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    CollectionReference foodRef= db.collection("Food");

    foodList = new ArrayList<>();
    madap = new MenuAdapter(foodList);
    menulist = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    menulist.setHasFixedSize(true);
    menulist.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    menulist.setAdapter(madap);

    db.collection("Food").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult())
                {
                   MenuItem mi = doc.toObject(MenuItem.class);
                   foodList.add(mi);

                }
                madap.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });


}
```

My `activity_main.xml` :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#f0ead6"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="132dp"
    android:text="Please select what you would like to eat"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:text="Menu."
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="186dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="355dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

My `MenuAdapter.java` :

```
 public class MenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MenuAdapter.ViewHolder> {
 public List<MenuItem> foodList;
 public MenuAdapter(List<MenuItem> foodList){
        this.foodList= foodList;
 }

  @Override
 public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.menu_item, parent, false);
     return  new ViewHolder(view);

 }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

     holder.mdof.setText(foodList.get(position).getDescof());
     holder.mnof.setText(foodList.get(position).getNameof());
     holder.mpof.setText(foodList.get(position).getPriceof());

 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
     return  foodList.size();
 }

 public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     View mView;
     public TextView mnof, mpof, mdof;

     public ViewHolder (View itemView){
         super(itemView);
         mView=itemView;
         mnof= mView.findViewById(R.id.nof);
         mpof= mView.findViewById(R.id.pof);
         mdof= mView.findViewById(R.id.dof);
     }}}
```

and lastly, the `MenuItem.java` class :

```
public class MenuItem {

public MenuItem(){}
public MenuItem(String nameof, String priceof, String descof) {
    this.nameof = nameof;
    this.priceof = priceof;
    this.descof = descof;
}

public String getNameof() {
    return nameof;
}

public void setNameof(String nameof) {
    this.nameof = nameof;
}

public String getPriceof() {
    return priceof;
}

public void setPriceof(String priceof) {
    this.priceof = priceof;
}

public String getDescof() {
    return descof;
}

public void setDescof(String descof) {
    this.descof = descof;
}

String nameof, priceof,descof;
```

}

Any comments regarding this would be helpful. There is no error or any kind of crash or exceptions.

Comment: Add madap.notifyDataSetChanged() after the for loop. If you have to do this because first you put a empty menuItem list in the adapter. But after that you are adding data in menuItem list. But you did not tell the adapter that you have added menuItems in the list. So  madap.notifyDataSetChanged() this will tell the adapter that you have changed the data in your menuItem list. Hope this will help.

Comment: @SkSuraj tried it. doesnt seem to help

Comment: Update question to include your notifydatasetchanfed location

Comment: And what's up with all these margins though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your adapter that you have add data in your list with

> yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

in your case the call is async from firestore, so add notify after the loop of adding item is done

```
db.collection("Food").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult())
                {
                   MenuItem mi = doc.toObject(MenuItem.class);
                   foodList.add(mi);

                }
                madap.notifyDataSetChanged()
                Log.d("Firelog","The XML file has issues.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work. but ive put it right after the foodList.add; statement.

Comment: hm, the notify should be outside loop so it called once. then have you tried logging your foodList to see the content or it size?

Comment: put a list.tostring after the for loop. now the app just crashes when opening the activity

Comment: how about the size?

Comment: hm, change it from List<> to ArrayList<>

Comment: if the size is not 0, then the data is fetched correctly. that notify should tell your adapter to refresh the data

Comment: the size is correct too. the number of things in the list is the same as the number of things in the database

Comment: do you have a repo for this?

Comment: if it possible i want to take a look

Comment: my git username is erwinkaaa